# How to identify different LDR photoresistors that have been mixed together?

Tags: identification, ldr, photoresistor

I purchased a variety pack of LDR photoresistors from eBay which includes GL5506, GL5516, GL5528, GL5537, GL5539.

The problem is that they all came in the same little bag and are visually identical. How can I sort them into their individual model numbers?

Comment: Read the specs, and measure them. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/331987/148363

Comment: I'm new to electronics and don't understand how to read the specs or what they mean.

Comment: I'm trying to follow an electronics tutorial online that says to use a LDR photoresistor but it doesn't specify the type so I bought a kit with a few different values to test with. But since they're mixed together, I don't know which is which when testing. Even if they produce different results, I don't know which one is responsible.

Comment: learn how to measure resistance with your multimeter.